# I'm trying to fit an image in between my horizontal nav bar and the body of text, but the body of text overlaps the image. How to add space below?

Tags: html, css, image, spacing

I know this is probably a common question, but  I just can't figure it out or find it on this site already.

[image: The image is being overlapped with text--I'm trying to have the text stay underneath it.]

HTML:

```
<div id="header-bg" >
  <img class="pic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e9/Rosalind_Franklin_%281920-1958%29.jpg" alt="Portrait of Rosalind Franklin with her hand on her chin, looking off to the left.">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-bg {display: flex; height: 100px; background: #AAB4AF; align-items: center;}
.pic { width: 600px; padding: 10px; margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of your `#header-bg` is smaller than your image, so your text is overlapping the image.

Answer (score -1):

If you want text to be hidden underneath picture you have to change it's z-index to the value lower than tag containing picture.

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).